ffmpeg: Remove invalid APP fields when streaming webcam to file
Logitech's proprietary MJPEG format embeds an inner H264 stream within the JPEG frames as APP attachments.
Presently, I'm solely piping the video stream straight into the output file.
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD User Facing" -c:v copy -rtbufsize 2000M output.mkv

How do I configure ffmpeg to remove that additional H264 stream while retaining the original MJPEG data, so that I may save storage? I could not find any useful option in the documentation.
